# What is the differnce between templateview and detailview in django?

Tags: django, django-models, view, django-views

**Each of this is for displaying a single template as we want,then what is actually it's difference which make it differ? And which is better for using and Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TemplateView`: Just a simple view to render an HTML template with provided context data.

`DetailView`: Generic view that works on a model object, expect a lookup kwarg in URL or get_object() can be overridden to return a single model object. and then pass that object in context data to be used in the template.